# How to create a resource from link_to with no direct association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models called Mom, Kid and Favorite.

```
class Mom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :favorites

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :user

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :user
```

I'm trying to favorite a Mom in the `kids/show` route:

```
class KidsController < ApplicationController

show
 @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
end

# link to favorite kid's mom at kids/show
link_to({ controller: 'favorites', action: 'create', id: @kid.mom.id }, { method: :post })
```

Now the problem I'm having is when I try to create it with this code in my favorites controller:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

def create
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:id])
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.build(params[:favorites])
  @favorites.mom_id = @kid.mom.id

  if @favorites.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "#{@favorite.mom.name.titleize} is one of your favorites now."
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

It throws me this error:

```
undefined method `mom' for nil:NilClass
```

Coming from this line I believe: `@favorites.mom_id = @kid.mom.id`

Why is this?

Comment: Your create doesn't have `@kid`.  Did you mean to put `@mom.id`

Comment: You don't have `@kid` initialized in your `create` method.Perhaps you mean `@mom.id` as @baloo said.

Comment: And also you need to change `@favorite` to `@favorites` in this line `redirect_to :back, notice: "#{@favorite.mom.name.titleize} is one of your favorites now."` to avoid another error in the future.

Comment: Following your logic, `@mom` is found with `params[:id]`, and the `mom_id` of `@favorites` (should be singular) is beeing updated with `@kid.mom.id` ===> why not using directly `@favorites.mom_id = @mom.id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Baloo, Pavan and MrYoshiji I was able to get it working. Just some small changes in my `create` action to get everything working:

```
def create
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:id])
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.build(params[:favorites])
  @favorite.mom_id = @mom.id

  if @favorite.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "#{@favorite.mom.name.titleize} is one of your favorites now."
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to be using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Check out [this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

**Method**

You've not set the `@kid` variable in your `create` class

--

When you receive `no method` errors, you'll typically find this is the issue:

> undefined method `mom' for nil:NilClass

The error here is not the `mom` method, it's the `nil:NilClass` - you've not set `@kid`.

I'd do this:

```
def create
  @mom = Mom.find(params[:id])
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.build(favorites_params)

  if @favorites.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "#{@favorite.mom.name.titleize} is one of your favorites now."
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end

private

def favorites_params
    params.require(:favorites).permit(:your, :attributes).merge(mom_id: @mom_id)
end
```